# US format mobile numbers in ios?

Tags: ios

I want display "1 (xxx)-(xxx)-(xxx)" in a `UITextfield` and only enter 10 digits.

- It's valid 1 to 9 numbers.
- It's starting only 1.
- If you enter 0 it's not taken.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done Us Phone Number validation in one of my projects. Hope this helps you.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 [textField performSelector:@selector(shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
 NSString *text = textField.text;

    NSString *acceptedcharacters = @"0123456789-/";
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:acceptedcharacters] invertedSet];
    const char * _char = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");
    if (isBackSpace == -8) {
        NSLog(@"deleted");
    }
    else {
        if (textField.text.length == 1) {

            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",text];
            return YES;
        }
        if (textField.text.length == 5) {

            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",text];
            return YES;
        }
        if (textField.text.length == 9) {

            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",text];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    //   if (textField == self.phoneNumber_txtField) {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 14) ? NO : YES;

    //  }

    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
 }
```

Comment: how to call this method.

Comment: This is the delegate of `UITextField`.  You set your texfield delegate as self. And place this method in your ViewController. It will be automatically called

Comment: If you want to call it explicitly then....
`-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 [textField performSelector:@selector(shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)];`
}

Comment: i was already set delegate method but it doesn't call.

Comment: you can call this explicitly in `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method using the perform selector. Like i mentioned above

Comment: I wouldn't call this explicitly I'd figure out why its not working with the delegate instead. So @phanindramandarapu have you set the delegate for the `UITextField` llike `setDelegate:self`? And have you added the `UITextFieldDelegate` to your interface file (`.h`)?

Comment: '-[UITextField shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f1b740'. this code is crash.  i was set delegate metthod.

Comment: its not allow zero's in UITextfield